# Google Maps Api - Info about road type, number of lanes

Tags: google-maps

Is it possible to get info about number of lanes of specific road, or some info about road type, for example if road is an motorway?

Comment: Is this something you are looking for?https://support.google.com/mapmaker/answer/1098048?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Google recently launched a Roads API that allows you to get the speed limit of any road. Looks like they don't have any more info than that for now:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/speed-limits